# Defining a nearest integer function for vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

I have a function:
$f(x) = \big\lceil x(q/t) \big\rfloor$, where $f\colon \;\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$; $q, t \in \mathbb{N}$, $x \in \mathbb{Z}$, and $\big\lceil a \big\rfloor$ denotes rounding $a$ to nearest integer.

I want to define a function that works exactly as one defined above, but which takes a vector as an argument, and in the end rounds each of the vector's elements. While the function without the rounding is $f(V) = V(q/t)$, I'm not sure how to include rounding of vector's elements.

Could it be as straightforward as $f(V) = \big\lceil V(q/t)\big \rfloor$, or do I need to write explicitly something like $\forall v \in V \; w = \big\lceil v(q/t)\big \rfloor$ to explicitly tell the reader that rounding affects each of vector's elements?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each element of $V$ is an integer, I would alter it slightly by pulling out the $V$:

$f(V) = \big\lceil (q/t)\big \rfloor V$

Then the rounding operator is only applied to the rational number $q/t$ and not the vector, and the result would be the same as you described.

Otherwise, defining how the rounding operator works on vectors would be helpful as I'm not sure it's standard.

Comment: This is not the same, even when $V$'s components are integers. For example, $\lceil \frac13 V\rfloor$ divides every component by $3$ and rounds to the nearest integer, and $\lceil \frac13 \rfloor V$ just multiplies everything by $0$.

Comment: Realized that just as I hit post. In that case, defining it seems like a good idea!